# How to integrate $\displaystyle\int e^{\frac{x^3}{3}} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

While solving $y'=x^2-e^y$ I'm stuck on the last step that requires to evaluate this integral.

$$\displaystyle\int e^{\frac{x^3}{3}} \mathrm{d}x$$

I don't know how to approach it. I know that it will result in incomplete Gamma function along with some other stuff.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\large n}}dx~=~\Gamma\bigg(1+\dfrac1n\bigg)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int e^{\frac{x^3}{3}} dx=-\int e^{-t} (-3t)^{-2/3}dt=(-3)^{-2/3}\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{3},t\big)=(-3)^{-2/3}\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{3},\frac{-x^3}{3}\big)$$
involving the Incomplete Gamma function.